# convert from unsigned char array to long c

Tags: c, long-integer

I read a long from a binary file into an unsigned char buffer using fread.

Now I would like to get the long. How do I do it?

```
unsigned char buffer[sizeof(long)];

fread(buffer, sizeof(long), 1, my_file);
```

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Surely you mean:

```
long buffer;
fread(&buffer, sizeof(long), 1, my_file);
```

Comment: @nnn You're welcome. I guess you can infer from this that you can read into any type of variable, not just char[].

Comment: Beware that this works only if the endianess used when the file was generated is the same of your system. In general it may be different (e.g. a file generated on a Motorola CPU and read on an x86 one). Moreover, the size of the "long" type may not match (e.g. 32 bits systems vs 64 bits). Generally speaking, you should specify the format used to store a "long" (how many bytes? which one is the most significant?).

Comment: @Giuseppe Thanks. All good points. I suspect that @nnn is still at a relatively early stage of learning where such issues are probably best pushed to one side.

Comment: (continued) If the long is stored with 4 bytes (assuming 8 bits per byte) in increasing order of significance, AND if your "long" is 32 bit or more, a portable way to do the conversion is "long v = b[0]+0x100*b[1]+0x10000*b[2]+0x1000000*b[3]". Note that the arithmetic operators behave the same on all systems, while bit-oriented ones don't. So let the compiler optimize the operation in the best way at you place ;-)

Comment: @Giuseppe How will any of this help OP?

Comment: @David: I just wanted to point some issues I have faced in the past, and a way to write an (almost) "portable" solution. "nnn" has probably to reimport data stored on the same system with its natural encoding, so you solution is ok. Bye!

Comment: @nnn If you are happy with the answer please can you mark it as accepted by clicking on the tick near the top of the answer and making it turn green.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to transfer the file between machines, you need to do this:

```
// will swap the byte order in little endian and not in big endian
long transform_standart_byte_order(long in) {
    return (((unsigned long) ((char*) &in)[0] << 56) |
           (((unsigned long) ((char*) &in)[1] << 48) |
           (((unsigned long) ((char*) &in)[2] << 40) |
           (((unsigned long) ((char*) &in)[3] << 32) |
           (((unsigned long) ((char*) &in)[4] << 24) |
           (((unsigned long) ((char*) &in)[5] << 16) |
           (((unsigned long) ((char*) &in)[6] <<  8) |
           (((unsigned long) ((char*) &in)[7]);
}

void write_long(FILE* my_file, long val) {
    val = transform_standart_byte_order(val);
    fwrite(val, sizeof(val), 1, my_file);
}

long read_long(FILE* my_file) {
    long val;
    fread(&val, sizeof(val), 1, my_file);
    return transform_standart_byte_order(val);
}
```